# IronPython: Is there an alternative to significant whitespace?

Tags: python, ironpython

For rapidly changing business rules, I'm storing IronPython fragments in XML files. So far this has been working out well, but I'm starting to get to the point where I need more that just one-line expressions.

The problem is that XML and significant whilespace don't play well together. Before I abandon it for another language, I would like to know if IronPython has an alternative syntax.

Comment: "XML and significant whilespace don't play well together"?  Really?  Why not?  Please be specific on what problem you're actually having.

Comment: An example or two would help illustrate your situation.

Comment: I'm speechless. I don't know if you two are just having a joke at my expense or if you are complete clueless to how XML tools and parsers treat whitespace outside of CDATA sections.

Comment: @Jonathan: "outside of CDATA sections"... I see your arrogance hasn't changed.

Comment: What's wrong with not wanting to litter my files with CDATA tags?

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: What's wrong with CDATA sections?  What's specific problem do you actually have? XML parsers I work with actually preserve **all** characters.  What problem are you having?

Comment: @Jonathan Allen, the XML spec says that all characters that aren't markup are delivered to the application as-is.  All whitespace should be returned from the parser.  Perhaps I am "completely clueless".  Could you enlighten me?  Also, XML does have whitespace declarations to help control whitespace handling.

Comment: And concerning whitespace in XML: Oracle AND Microsoft AND many others (ask google) prove you wrong, Jonathan: http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/wang-whitespace.html http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx

Comment: All I want is something that will let my users write code like `<Rule Name="Markup" Formula="(Account.PricingLevel + 1) * .05">`. I don't want to teach them about CDATA or spend all day being paranoid that someone will open a file in Visual Studio and wipe out all of the indentions. IronPython isn't the right language for that, so I'll look look at IronRuby or another DLR langauge. It's no big deal.

Comment: @Delnan, did you read that article? It clearly says "By default, Microsoft XML Core Services (MSXML) does not honor the xml:space attribute.". It also says "Although XML processors preserve all white space in element content, they frequently normalize it in attribute values. Tabs, carriage returns, and spaces are reported as single spaces." And who wants to add  `xml:space="preserve"` to every single element?

Comment: @Ned, people don't edit XML files with specifications. They edit them with tools, many of which like to 'helpfully' reformat the file.

Comment: @Jonathan: thanks for the example.  I didn't imagine you were putting multi-line code in an attribute.  You are right: XML has very different whitespace handling for attributes and elements.  Making questions more explicit will always get you higher-quality answers, and help avoid misunderstandings and conflicts.

Comment: @Jonathan: if you pursue this design, I'd suggest avoiding multi-line attributes.  It's well outside typical XML use, and will likely cause you grief no matter what language you choose.  If your users are going to be entering multi-line code, they won't like it being reformatted any more than Python does.  Putting the code in an element will likely avoid frustration (and let you continue to use Python!).

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for IronPython to solve a problem with XML or your XML editing tools. If your tools are striping out data from CDATA sections then your tools are broken. If you're not using CDATA to store script content in XML, then you're miss-using XML. Either way, this isn't IronPython/Python's fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IronPython doesn't have an alternate syntax.  It's an implementation of Python, and Python uses significant indentation (all languages use significant whitespace, not sure why we talk about whitespace when it's only indentation that's unusual in the Python case).

Comment: Ok, then I guess I've got to drop it on favor of something else.

Comment: You might also have to give your users some whitespace sensitivity training if you use ironruby: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2008/7/1/whitespace-sensitivity

Comment: Damn. Thanks for the warning, that is exactly the kind of thing that is going to cause me headaches down the road.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> from __future__ import braces
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from __future__ import braces

                                 ^
SyntaxError: not a chance
```

Comment: Same here. But in all seriousness, the one thing I like about JavaScript is that by using braces it allows you to put everything on one line. Too bad there isn't a production quality DLR implementaion yet.

Answer (score 3):

> All I want is something that will let my users write code like

Ummm... Don't do this.  You don't actually want this.  In the long run, this will cause endless little issues because you're trying to force too much content into an attribute.

Do this.

```
<Rule Name="Markup">
    <Formula>(Account.PricingLevel + 1) * .05</Formula>
</Rule>
```

You should try not to have significant, meaningful stuff in attributes.  As a general XML design policy, you should use tags and save attributes for names and ID's and the like.  When you look at well-done XSD's and DTD's, you see that attributes are used minimally.

Having the body of the rule in a separate tag (not an attribute) saves much pain.  And it allows a tool to provide correct CDATA sections.  Use a tool like Altova's XML Spy to assure that your tags have space preserved properly.

Comment: While I indend to offer that as an option to my users, that doesn't change the fact that XML editing tools will still frag the indention levels inside the Formula element.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can set the [`xml:space="preserve"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space) attribute or use a [`<![CDATA[`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-cdsection) to avoid other issues, with for example quotes and greater equal signs.

Comment: xml:space="preserve" is actually the default, so shouldn't need to be specified.

Comment: I do exactly what you are and xml:space-"preserve" works great. My rules are often more than one line so this is common and I'll gladly have the noise vs finding "something else".

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the already mentioned CDATA sections, there's [pindent.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/pindent.py) which can, among others, fix broken indentation based on comments a la `#end if` - to quote the linked file:

> When called as "pindent -r" it assumes its input is a Python program with block-closing comments but with its indentation messed up, and outputs a properly indented version.
>
> ...
>
> A "block-closing comment" is a comment of the form '# end <keyword>' where  is the keyword that opened the block.  If the opening keyword is 'def' or 'class', the function or class name may be repeated in the block-closing comment as well.  Here is an example of a program fully augmented with block-closing comments:

```
def foobar(a, b):
    if a == b:
        a = a+1
    elif a < b:
        b = b-1
        if b > a: a = a-1
        # end if
    else:
        print 'oops!'
    # end if
# end def foobar
```

It's bundeled with CPython, but if IronPython doesn't have it, just grab it from the repository.